# A little problem with a binomial identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have to compute the quantity $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{k}{n-k}$.

Using the identity $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and reindexing the sum, it's easy to see the previous sum becomes

$$
\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-2} \binom{n-1}{j} \frac{1}{(n-j-1)^2}
$$

But now I don't know how to continue. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{k}{n-k}&=&\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{n-k}{k}=(2^n-1)+n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k}\\&=&(2^n-1)+n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x}\,dx\\&=&(2^n-1)+n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k}-1}{k}\end{eqnarray*}$$
is easier to bound but cannot be simplified much further.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if we use binomial theorem in the integral we can do something

Comment: @Federico: doing that just gives back the original sum. However, if we exploit $\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}=1+a+\ldots+a^{n-1}$ we may rearrange the original sum in a more manageable sum, just see the updated answer,